# C++ reinterpret_cast object to string and back

Tags: c++, string, object, casting, reinterpret-cast

I just discovered reinterpret_cast in C++ and I am trying to learn more about it. I wrote this code:

```
struct Human{
    string name;
    char gender;
    int age;
    Human(string n, char g, int a) : name(n), gender(g), age(a) {}
};

int main()
{
    Human h("John", 'M', 26);
    char* s = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&h);
    Human *hh = reinterpret_cast<Human*>(s);
    cout << hh->name << " " << hh->gender << " " << hh->age << endl;
}
```

It works pretty well, exactly as expected. Now I want convert the `char *` to an `std::string` and then from this string get back the `Human` object:

```
int main()
{
    Human h("John", 'M', 26);
    char* s = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&h);

    string str = s;
    Human *hh = reinterpret_cast<Human*>(&str);

    cout << hh->name << " " << hh->gender << " " << hh->age << endl; // prints wrong values
}
```

Does anyone have an idea to overcome this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Although there are ways to make this work, this smells funny. In fact, this smells like an http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . So, what is the _real_ problem you think you need to solve using this approach?

Comment: That first example is a gross violation of [the strict aliasing rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Comment: Well, as it's explained in the linked article, a "char *" is exempt from aliasing. Even if this is actually OK, it's still not recommended, though.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am actually trying to send objects through sockets in native C++ (I mean without using any external library). I saw this [https://gist.github.com/codemonkey85/5860625](https://gist.github.com/codemonkey85/5860625) and I thought it may work for sockets...?

Comment: @A.Omar Ah, then yes you can convert a pointer to an object to another pointer. But, and this is important, trying to send anything complex over a socket will in almost all cases not work as expected. Take the normal `std::string` for example. A `std::string` object doesn't actually contain an actual string, it contains a *pointer* to a string, and sending a `std::string` object will send the pointer and not the data (string) it points to. In the other process, that pointer you receive is not going to point to the same thing (if at any valid memory at all).

Comment: @A.Omar: While this can theoretically work sometimes it's not a good idea. Firstly your structs cannot contain a single pointer (or a pointer in an object) because it makes no sense. Additionally numerous things such as bitness, type size, packing, compiler, compiler version and endianness differences can change the way a struct is laid out in memory across platforms. If you need to serialize an object - just write it byte by byte in a known format.

Answer (score 1):

In your second program when you do

```
string str = s;
```

you create a completely new object that is totally unrelated to the pointer `s`. Getting the address from `str` will give you a pointer to `str`, and not the "string" it contains.

Also, using `reinterpret_cast` is a way to tell the compiler "I know what I am doing", and if you don't actually know what's happening then you will undoubtedly march into the territory of *undefined behavior* which is what will happen when you try to initialize `str` with the "string" pointed to by `s`, since it's not really a string.

Comment: Not to mention that since `s` isn't even a pointer to a proper C string, at best you will get something meaningless in the `std::string`, and in the worst case your program will crash when it tries to read from unallocated memory.

Comment: How does `string str = s`; possibly create an object  unrelated to pointer `s`, when `s` was essential to its construction? Do you mean unrelated to it's address?

Comment: @GManNickG I didn't say a new pointer, said a new *object*, and attempting to get the address of the new object will result in a pointer to that new object and that is not related to `s` in any way.

Comment: I understand your sentence, I'm saying "you create a completely new object that is totally unrelated to the pointer s" is misleading and adds confusion to your answer. `str` is very related to the pointer `s`, it's entire (attempt) at initialization is via the pointer `s`.

Comment: @GManNickG: Even though the constructor takes in `s` it does not store the actual value of `s` in any way within the object. All it does is copy the (nonsensical) data pointed to it into the `std::string`. Therefore I don't think the resulting `std::string` has a lasting relationship to `s`.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: .......I know how `std::string` works. Now you're moving the goalpost from "has a relationship to `s`" to "has a lasting relationship to `s`."

Comment: @GManNickG: And I think you're just pointlessly arguing semantics now.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: I've been consistent since the first comment. The answer loses clarity, especially for a beginner, because of its attempt to completely remove any relationship between `str` and `s`, instead of explain it.

Comment: @GManNickG But the pointer `s` is only passed as an argument to the constructor (in this case), that's the closest relationship the string object `str` and the pointer `s` have. Once the constructor returns how is `str` and `s` related in any way? They aren't. The string object `str` has its own pointer, that is pointing to some completely other memory than `s`.

Comment: @GManNickG Lets say that `s` is actually pointing to a valid string, and you do `std::string str = s`, would you expect `str[0] = 'F'`  change the string pointed to by `s`? Or doing `s[0] = 'B'`, would that change `str[0]`? No it doesn't, they are simply not related in any way.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Like I said, I know how `std::string` works. Beginners don't. Telling them that `s` has nothing to do with `str` isn't useful. Explaining that it's used to tell `str` what initial contents to have is. No, of course I don't expect `str` to be related to `s` after construction, that's not the same as "a completely new object that is totally unrelated to the pointer s".

Comment: @A.Omar It just happens that the first member of `h` is a `std::string` object, and most likely the first member of that `std::string` is a pointer to the actual string. This is, however, really crossing the line into *undefined behavior*. While `s` might be a pointer to `char` (and as such act like a C-style string) it's not actually a real string. This is the danger of using `reinterpret_cast` (as well as C-style casting).

Comment: This entire comment thread would be most confusing for a beginner at all, though, so I'm just going to delete it later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104734/discussion-between-gmannickg-and-joachim-pileborg).